# If A is inveritble and $\det(B)=0$ (so $B$ non invertible), is $A+B$ always (non)invertible, or can be both?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is an invertible matrix ($\det(A)!=0$) while B is a non-invertible matrix because $\det(B)=0$. Is $A+B$ always invertible or always not invertible?

I'm sure about $AB$ (always not invertible) but I don't know about $A+B$.

Comment: inverisble -> inver$\color{red}{tible}$

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

This does not need to be invertible. Let
$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{B} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

$\mathbf{A}$ is invertible, $\mathbf{B}$ is singular and the sum $\mathbf{A + B}$ is also singular.

Comment: (+1) Of course, there are cases where $A+B$ is invertible (e.g. if $B$ is the zero matrix and $A$ is any invertible matrix), so the answer to OP's question is "sometimes it is invertible and sometimes it is not".

Comment: @Joe For me, if you ask "is $A+B$ is invertible", it appears like a general statement. So the answer would be "no" (in general, not). Like asking, "if $p$ is a prime, and $n$ is composite, is $n+p$ prime?" No, in general not. On the other hand, asking "If $p$ and $q$ are odd primes, is $p+q$ even? Yes, true in general.